# Zend_Log: How to change the log file permissions

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-log

I'm executing my script from web interface as well as a cron job. I'm using `Zend_Log` for logging and the log file is daily rotating (`mylog_YYYY-MM-DD.log`). If I execute my script from web in the day start, then my cron job is failing due to log file permission problem.
I'm ok with provide `666` permissions to my log file. How can I apply the permissions using `Zend_Log`.

Thanks in advane.
-Venkat

Comment: Perhaps you should set the permissions to the folder instead ?

Comment: my logs/ dir have full 777 permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the web interface and the cron job run as the same user and you shouldn't have this issue.  I guess that the website runs as one user (www, apache, etc) and your cron job runs as your specific user so whichever process ends up creating the file first makes it inaccessible to the other user.

If you're comfortable with permissions of 666, just use the php code:

```
chmod($log_file, 0666);
```

in the code where the log file gets created.

Comment: thank you @drew010. can you let me know how to run the web, cron with same user.

Comment: If you are using Apache, you can install a module like [suPHP](http://suphp.org) or use FastCGI to run your PHP scripts and when the scripts run they will run as the user that owns the script or whatever user you specify rather than the user the server runs as.